# Force browser to reload cached HTML

Tags: html, browser-cache

I am adding features to my site, and I forgot to set the HTML expires header for my changing HTML content...

I have set the HTML expires headers correctly now, but current users still have the old HTML & expires headers set... so they still load the cached HTML

how do I force those user's loading the cached HTML to load the newest version? (using server-side code or javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Pass a random number on the query string dynamically, which makes the browser to make a new request to the server for getting the content

Answer (score 0):

Pressing Ctrl+F5 should do the trick in Chrome/Firefox

Comment: OP is trying to get remote users to expire their cached version automatically.

Comment: He should edit and explain better the question :( Thanks for clearing it out :P